# My onclick not working the second time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was trying to change the attribute within the form, whenever the user clicks the the sign up or register. So the form will change accordingly, however once the user clicks on register they can no longer click login.

```
 <?php
 session_start();



    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        include_once("php/config/database.php"); 
        $Email = strip_tags($_POST['Email']);
        $dbPassword = strip_tags($_POST['Password']);

        $Email = stripslashes($Email);
        $dbPassword = stripslashes($dbPassword);

        $Email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $Email);
        $dbPassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $dbPassword);



        $sql = ("SELECT * FROM 'Users' WHERE Email='$Email' AND Password='$dbPassword' LIMIT 1");
        $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
        $UserID = $row['UserID'];
        $dbpass = $row['Password'];

        if($dbPassword == $dbpass) {
            $_SESSION['Email'] = $Email;
            $_SESSION['UserID'] = $UserID;
            header("Location: account.php");
        } 
        else 
        {
            echo "You didn't enter the correct details!";
        }

    } 


?>


<!DOCTYPE html>

<html >
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>background</title>




        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
 <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>

     <script src="js/index.js"></script>




  </head>

  <body>



     <form action="index.php" method="POST" id="search-theme-form">
  <div class="box">


    <h1 id="logintoregister">
      Login
    </h1>
    <div class="group show">
      <input class="inputMaterial" type="text" name="FirstName" />
      <label>First Name</label>
    </div>
    <div class="group show">
      <input class="inputMaterial" type="text" name="Surname" />
      <label>Surname</label>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
      <input class="inputMaterial" type="email" name="Email" required/>
      <label>Email</label>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
      <input class="inputMaterial" type="password" id="password"
      name="Password" required/> <label>Password</label>
    </div>
    <div class="group show">
      <input class="inputMaterial" type="password" id=
      "confirm_passwor" /> <label>Confirm Password</label>
    </div>


    <button id="buttonlogintoregister" type="submit" name=
    "submit">Login</button>




    <p id="plogintoregister"> By registering, You accept all terms and conditons</p>
    <p id="textchange" onclick="register()">Sign Up</p>


</div>
</form>



      <!-- Related demos -->




 <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>

     <script src="js/index.js"></script>




</body>
</html>
```

> JS file

```
function register(){
var cont = 0;   

     cont++;

        if(cont==1){
            $('.box').animate({height:'600px'}, 550);
            $('.show').css('display','block');
            $('#logintoregister').text('Register');
            $('#buttonlogintoregister').text('Register');
            $('#plogintoregister').text("Sei gia' registrato?");
            $('#textchange').text('Login');
            $('#search-theme-form').removeAttr("action").attr("action", "signup_destination.php");



        }
        else
        {

            $('.show').css('display','none');
            $('.box').animate({height:'365px'}, 550);
            $('#logintoregister').text('Login');
            $('#buttonlogintoregister').text('Login');
            $('#plogintoregister').text("Non sei iscritto?");
            $('#textchange').text('Register');
            $('#search-theme-form').removeAttr("action").attr("action", "index.php");


            cont = 0;


        }
}
```

Comment: You should really format your code better. You don't need multiple line breaks all over the place. It makes your code harder to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You keep reseting the cont var each time the function runs,

```
var cont = 0;
```

So you will always enter the first part of the if.

Take the var count out of the function:

```
var cont = 0;
function register(){
..
..
.
}
```

This way he wont reset each time the function runs to 0 and the rest should work.

Comment: Thanks BinaryGhost! you fixed my problem

Comment: Glad to help :), just mark me as the answer please, so future users can see it. Welcome to stackoverflow